# How do I write a regular expression for Strings and specific characters?

Tags: javascript

Hey I want to write a regular expression that only allows the alphabet (a-z) and only those two specific characters - and only 1 whitespace. Some people have two (like Peter-James Lastname) that are connected with a dash.

This should be allowed:

- My-Name
- My Nääüöme
- David Silá
- Name-ádbR

Upper and Lowercases should also be allowed

This sould not be allowed:

- Name123
- ?!,.; (pretty much every specific character except `-`)
- 332
- empty name
- only whitespace

So far my expression looks like this:

```
if(input_vorname.value.match (/\d+/g)
```

Comment: This looks like you are trying to make a RegEx in JavaScript but you tagged the question with PHP - which one are you really interested in?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just a beginner. It is javascript.

Comment: I don't fully understand what's allowed in your RegEx. Could you provide some examples which strings should match and which not?

Comment: Of course yes maybe it was not very clear.

Comment: Of course yes maybe it was not very clear. I want to use this expression for my formular, where I check the name. Some people have two (like Peter-James Lastname) that are connected with a dash.

This should be allowed:
1.  My-Name 
2.  My Nääüöme
3.  David Silá
4.  Name-ádbR
Upper and Lowercases should also be allowed

This sould not be allowed:
1. Name123
2. ?!,.; (pretty much every specific character except  -
3. 332
4. empty name
5. only whitespace

Comment: Do not add additional informations using the comments, edit your question istead.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]+[\ |\-][a-zA-Z]+` you also need to add your language specific characters like:
`[a-zA-Zäüö]+[\ |\-][a-zA-Zäüö]+` and also capital letters. Use this as a hint, although it can surly be done better